# Referencing multiple sheets in excel

Tags: excel

I got this formula but I need to add more sheets to it. So instead of only Sheet1 there also need to be Sheet2 and Sheet3 in this formula, with the same columns.

`=SUM.IF(Sheet1!A2:A100; "=" & TODAY)`

Comment: Why not the sum of 3 formulas?

Comment: I don't know how this works. I'm an excel noob.

Comment: (Untested): `=SUM.IF(Sheet1!A2:A100; "=" & TODAY) + SUM.IF(Sheet2!A2:A100; "=" & TODAY) + SUM.IF(Sheet3!A2:A100; "=" & TODAY)`. there might be a better way, but that should work.

Comment: Alright, thanks. If someone knows a shorter way to put this, let me know. There might be 10+ sheets in the future

Comment: This might help: https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets